# How to generate evolutions diffs?

Tags: hibernate, playframework

I am using Play! Framework with Hibernate.
What is the best way to generate evolution which contains only diffs (not all schema)?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174366/how-one-should-handle-incremental-database-schema-evolution) and it turns out there is no standard way to do it automatically.

In my case, I ended up generating new schema and semi-manually (by text diffing) generated v2 evolution (as UPs and DOWNs to v1 schema).